# Error message BAD_GATEWAY on app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm receiving this 502 and bad_gateway error on my app engine ,Can anyone resolve my issue and indicate what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error code 502 with BAD_GATEWAY in the message usually indicates that App Engine terminated the application because it ran out of memory. The default App Engine flexible VM only has 1GB of memory, with only 600MB available for the application container.